# Most efficient way to make multiple quick API calls without spamming them?

Tags: javascript, node.js

By making this API call, I'll receive a JSON file which looks similar to this:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "a": 123456789,
            "b": 1
        },
        {
            "a": 272727272,
            "b": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

(This is just an example, I wanted to make it as simple as I could but there are usually like 20 or 30 objects)

I want to make an API call to http://example.com/objects[0].a and another to http://example.com/objects[1].a and add them together into 'responseA'.

Is there a better solution to making these calls than a loop for however many objects there are (as this takes a lot of time and can easily hit my limit for calls in a second).

Any better solutions?

Edit1: Removed useless tag

Comment: If a (singular) response contains an array of the the objects you need (just access `responseObj.objects[0]`, `responseObj.objects[1]`, etc), what is the purpose of further API calls, I'm not getting it?

Comment: So the original API call is to a stats site to get a bunch of stats for individual matches for a user. All of these individual stats pages have their own information which I need to combine. The first API call gets all of the links for the individual pages. I need to call each page to get the information.

Comment: Please share how you are currently making the API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the package `axios`. It is quite handy to use in such cases.

Example for making multiple requests:

```
const objectZeroURL = 'http://example.com/objects[0].a';
const objectOneURL = 'http://example.com/objects[1].a';

function getObjectZero() {
  return axios.get(objectZeroURL);
}

function getObjectOne() {
  return axios.get(objectOneURL);
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  axios.all([getObjectZero(), getObjectOne()])
    .then(axios.spread((dataFromZero, dataFromOne) => {

      name = [];

      // Segregating data from the response object
      users.data.forEach((user) => {
        name.push(user.name);
      });

      // Segregating data from the response object
      posts.data.forEach((post) => {
        ...
      });

      // Writing back response to display
      for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
          res.write('=> ' + name[i]);
      }

      res.end();
    })).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).render('error');
    });
});
```

I hope this stands up to the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Anytime :) Reach out if you have any queries.

Comment: @ElkTF2 This does not appear to take into account the rate-limiting you were asking for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to map your array of objects to Promises such that only a few requests get sent off each second. Here's an example of code that sends out only 3 requests per second, using a `delay` helper function, and uses `Promise.all` to indicate when all requests have been completed:

```js
const objs={"objects":[{"a":123456789,"b":1},{"a":272727272,"b":1},{"a":123456789,"b":1},{"a":272727272,"b":1},{"a":123456789,"b":1},{"a":272727272,"b":1},{"a":123456789,"b":1},{"a":272727272,"b":1}]};

function makeRequest(a) {
  console.log('Making a request ' + a);
  return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 200, 'response str'));
}
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const requests = objs.objects.map((object, i) => (
  delay(1000 * Math.floor(i / 3))
  .then(() => makeRequest(object.a))
));
Promise.all(requests)
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(responses);
  });
```